# Windows task scheduler with http path

Tags: windows, coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

Trying to execute a task scheduler from Windows. Have given a http path of the required file
to be executed. The history seems to be showing as its triggered, but the hit is not received at
the other end as have written a log to identify the hit. No log is created which means the expected code is not executed.

Is it possible to give a http url for windows task scheduler? The destination file is written in coldfusion language.

Comment: Not directly, no. But there are several indirect ways to achieve this. You can create a Windows Task Scheduler basic task to run a program, then choose your browser exe as the program to run - eg full path to iexplore.exe or chrome.exe - then specify the http URL as the argument to pass to the program. Or you could create a Powershell script which uses Invoke-WebRequest or System.Net.WebRequest to perform a GET request, and schedule a task to run your script. Or you could use the Coldfusion Task scheduler instead of WTS, either directly from the CF Admin gui or using the `<cfschedule>` tag.

Comment: A google search of `windows scheduled task run http` yields many results.  I read a few of them and concluded that this can't be done directly.  You must create a batch file that makes the http request.  This batch file can then be scheduled.  Mind you, I didn't actually try anything.

Comment: @SevRoberts you should post your comment as an answer to this question. With a little more detail added to the answer.

Comment: I wonder why CF's scheduler isn't a better solution.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.                                                             
 Understand the better way to do is to use coldfusion(CF 11) scheduler and was using it for past four years successfully. It stopped suddenly from last month end without any trace to troubleshoot.
The scheduler log had only message 'Connection Failure: Status code unavailable'.                                                                                              
   Therefore was looking for an alternate solution to execute the same.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I would try to tacle down the problem that is causing the connection failure. It can have many things causing it, such as encoding missmatch, SSL handshake problems and more. Do a cftry cfcatch all and dump all the error scope, it should tell you in error.detail more about the cause.

Comment: `Connection Failure: Status code unavailable` is usually an SSL/TLS issue. If you have the ErrorDetail with that statusCode then we could narrow down further. If the log does not give this then you can use cfhttp from the same box to hit the same URL that the scheduler was hitting, then dump the error. If you see `I/O Exception: peer not authenticated` then the target has recently renewed their SSL certificate (or started redirecting http to https) and you need to add the new cert to your CF keystore. If you get `PKIX path building failed` then it's probably a missing intermediate cert.